# How to remove border input below li tag?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have this input with languages tabs:

[image]

I need to make it like  this:

[image]

My problem with the border when any languages active tab!

my code in English:

```
<div>
    <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
        <label class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">
            Categroy Name
        </label>
        <div class="inline-flex items-center text-gray-700 list-none space-x-1">
            <li class="px-4 rounded border-r border-t border-l cursor-pointer">
                Arabic
            </li>
            <li class="px-4 rounded border bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer">
                English
            </li>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="category_title" class="focus:ring-indigo-500 rounded focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm border-gray-300">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it work by changing the radius to top only (`rounded-t`), moving your div and tab each -1px down (`-mb-px`) and adding a white background (`bg-white`).

This is also the solution of [the official tabs component](https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/tabs).

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
    <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
        <label class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">
            Category Name
        </label>
        <div class="-mb-px inline-flex items-center text-gray-700 list-none space-x-1">
            <li class="-mb-px px-4 rounded-t border-r border-t border-l cursor-pointer bg-white">
                Arabic
            </li>
            <li class="px-4 rounded-t border bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer">
                English
            </li>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="category_title" class="focus:ring-indigo-500 rounded focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full border border-grey-300">
</div>
```

---

Comment: '-mb-px' so I add this class when the class is active?

Comment: @sime exactly, you add this to the <li> and change the "bg-gray-200" to "bg-white". Also "-mb-px" should be added to the <div> that contain the 2 <li>

Comment: Found this example: https://codepen.io/davidgrzyb/pen/dyYORJd?editors=1010